# Installing odoo app on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, odoo

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.04 and am trying to install odoo 8.0 but am getting this error:

```
$ apt-get install odoo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odoo : Depends: python-pypdf but it is not installable
        Recommends: postgresql but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: python-gevent but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do?

Comment: hie am now having this issue The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odoo : Depends: python-pypdf but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy odoo` and `apt-get install -s odoo python-pypdf postgresql python-gevent`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo 8.0 has dependencies that `apt` tries to install. However, some of these dependencies no longer have a candidate for your Ubuntu release. That is because Odoo 8.0 is already quite old, wherease your Ubuntu release is brand new.

Try a newer release of Odoo, like 9.0 or 10.0.